# powershell variable in get-ASUser

Tags: powershell, date, double

I am collecting birthday and other informations from `Activedirectory` using this

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(extensionAttribute4 -like "Aktiv") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -SearchBase "OU=*****,OU=*****,OU=*****,DC=*****,DC=****" -Properties * | select name, mail, extensionAttribute1
```

extensionAttribute1 is the birthday and are type duble.
It is possible to convert the double to a date with this:

```
$date.AddDays(+27137).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
```

but how do I use it in this code:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(extensionAttribute4 -like "Aktiv") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -SearchBase "OU=*****,OU=*****,OU=*****,DC=*****,DC=****" -Properties * | select name, mail, extensionAttribute1
```

Comment: Where is `$date` defined, and what is the significance of the number `27137`?  In general, you can use calculated properties with `Select-Object` to generate new properties from those passed through the pipeline; see Example 4 here: [Select-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6)

Comment: $date = Get-Date "1899-12-30"

Comment: 27137 is number of days since 1899-12-30

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your extra information, and @VivekKumarSingh's answer, the following should show the correct information:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(extensionAttribute4 -like "Aktiv") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} `
           -SearchBase "OU=*****,OU=*****,OU=*****,DC=*****,DC=****" `
           -Properties * | 
    Select-Object Name, Mail, @{ Name = 'Birthday'; Expression = {$date.AddDays($_.extensionAttribute1).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your help. The above solution works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but  can you try this -

```
Get-ADUser -Filter  {(extensionAttribute4 -like "Aktiv") -and (Enabled -eq $true)} -SearchBase "OU=*****,OU=*****,OU=*****,DC=*****,DC=****" -Properties * | select name, mail, @{ Name = 'Birthday'; Expression = {$date.AddDays(+27137).ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")}}
```

Comment: OK, but how do I use extensionAttribute1 insted of value 27137?

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Comment: No date is written?